# Which flag should I use for too much code?

Tags: support, flags, code

I just got the privilege to edit or review questions and answers. Now I'm faced with the question: what flag is the right one, when the question includes too much code?

Surely **Needs author edit**, but then there are many choices.

- **Needs more focus**
  *This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.*
- **Needs details or clarity**
  *This question should include more details and clarify the problem.*

Does it need more focus? Certainly it does, but the question maybe is asking only one question, so that's not the right one. Needs details or clarity? No it actually needs less.

The other options don't seem right to me either.

Comment: "Needs details or clarity" isn't quite wrong - sure, it may not need more *details* but the extra unneeded details detract from the *clarity*. So, the question needs more of the latter. However, the "Needs debugging details" is even more specific, as it reminds people that they need to provide a ***minimal*** example. The whole code base is far from minimal.

Comment: Why was this closed? None of the duplicate answers actually answers the question of which flag to use for too much code. And as it appears not everybody agrees on the right answer...

Comment: There is only one correct answer. The answers to the duplicates all the say the same thing: such questions should be closed for lacking a minimal, verifiable example.

Comment: The flag however doesn't say *'the shortest code and no more than the shortest code'*. I provided the reason why it should be closed myself, there is too much code, and from that follows that there is more than the minimum reproducible example, all the other answers don't say more than that. And at least two other people thought that another flag might be also right. I kind of think that the flags aren't clear enough in their description.

Comment: "*The flag however doesn't say 'the shortest code and no more than the shortest code'.*" does it need to? You've only added double affirmation on the same wording. We don't really do that for any other flags "It's absolutely lacks focus" or "It most certainly is opinion based". The wording is unnecessary. It already says that we need the *shortest* code [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) does emphasise that you shouldn't supply more code than necessary (something that I don't think many would call "shortest" or "minimal").

Comment: It does say that, @Oskar. "Shortest" is a superlative (the "-est" suffix); it means the absolute shortest possible code that can be used to reproduce the problem. Code that is not the shortest is too long. However, we do not generally enforce that draconian of an interpretation. But it *is* what the close reason says, and it is appropriate to use it when the code is far too long.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use

- **Needs debugging details**
  The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.**

which is available as an option if you first select

- **A community-specific reason**
  This question doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline.